Query to return certain fields from mongodb collection using @Query filter is not working
The REST API must only return certain fields from the collection when the user makes a GET request. I added the @Query filter to the repository class as follows:
@Query(value="{ 'clientId' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'clientId' : 1, 'siteUrl' : 1, 'siteName' : 1, 'dateAdded' : 1 }")
 Page<sites> findByClientId(Object clientId, Pageable pageable);

But it still returns the entire document for that request and includes all fields even though the values are null or 0. The service method as well seems correct.
 public Page<sites> findSitesByCustomer(String name, Pageable pageable){

         Clients client = userRepository.findclientsByUsername(name);

        if(client.getClientName() != null || !client.getClientName().isEmpty()) {
            int clientId = client.getId();
            return sitesRepository.findByClientId((long) client.getId(), pageable);
        }

        return Page.empty();
    }

Is there something I am missing?
EDIT:
tried to exclude the fields explicitly with 'maxCount':0 for example but get error cannot do exclusion on field in inclusion project.
EDIT:
tried exclude only but the fields still show with 0 or null values.
I have researched for answers with this and if springboot states that it excludes or includes fields then this should work and not just exclude the field values. Why am I voted down for this?

Are you sure that format of @Query is correct.

I am not sure but you can use native query along with custom java class in which your object will be returned.

yes it is correct. The custom class could work I guess and will try that if I don't find a solution to this. Thanks

So I was able to get help on another site and the suggestion worked:
Use the fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@Document(collection="sites")
public class sites {

